# Merging Excel files by Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Im trying to use Pandas to mix several xlsx into one.
Starter columns are equal for all files.
Trailing columns are different, but sometime have same name in original files.

Like this one (column names here):

- 1 file - A B C **X** Y Z
- 2 file - A B C M **N** O
- 3 file - A B C **X** **N** K

I want to get summary file like this:

- A B C **X** Y Z M **N** O K - with all mixed data.

But for unclear for me reasons im get something like that:

- A B C **X** Y Z M **N.1** O **N.2** K

Some columns clearly get into one column as shold be, but some added as different with adding dots and number to its name.

Initial names of columns are equal (i mean N column in 2nd & 3rd file in sample above).

For what reason this can happens?

Part of code that i use here:

```
    CombinedFrame=[]
    for file in glob.glob("TeamsReports\*.xlsx"): 
        df_TReps = pd.read_excel(file)
        CombinedFrame.append(df_TReps) 
    SummRep = pd.concat(CombinedFrame, ignore_index=True)
    SummRep.to_excel("!SummRep.xlsx", index=False)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
Combined_frame = pd.concat([Combined_frame, df_TReps],ignore_index = True)
```

Also check if data type of N's are Same or not.